# createElement('mat-menu') in a directive

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I want to create a mat-menu in a custom directive (.directive.ts), like below:

```
const menu: MatMenu = this.renderer.createElement('mat-menu');
this.renderer.setAttribute(menu, '#menu', 'pagMenu');
```

That code give me the error:

> DOMException: Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': '#menu' is not a valid attribute name.

What can I do, to set the '#menu' attribute, which is needed to trigger the opening?
Or something to work around that.

Here's the final result I want: (I already did the main buttons)
[image: final result]

Comment: do you expect to use `menu` in the component template, where thisdirective is used?

Comment: The directive will be used in a mat-paginator component. I want to have a button with a menu, to show some hidden page numbers as buttons.

Comment: could you provide a code sample, how you want your directive to be used?

Comment: I want it to be simple:

`<mat-paginator paginator [length]="600" [pageSize]="20" [hidePageSize]='true' (page)="1"></mat-paginator>`

Comment: I added a picture of the final result I want above

Comment: `#menu` is indeed not a valid attribute. I do not understand what you're trying to do. What do you expect to happen when you try to set the value of an attribute `#menu`?

Comment: @LazarLjubenović is for have a button with the attribute `[matMenuTriggerFor]="menu"`, that triggers that menu.